# The problem with creating a library for codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, frameworks, php

I create ​​a library and function `show`, outputs (results) the Library sent for control,
but there's in view page following error. What is in your opinion problem?

i put outputs to Controller as `return $info; return $results; return $offset;` and they of Controller `echo` in view as: `$data['num_count'] = $info; $data['results'] = $results; $data['offset'] = $offset;`

error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>  Severity: Notice
>  Message:
>   Undefined variable: info
>  Filename: admin/accommodation.php
>   Line Number: 29
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>  Severity: Notice
>  Message:
>   Undefined variable: results
>  Filename: admin/accommodation.php
>   Line Number: 30
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\Siran-mehdi\system\core\Loader.php(679) : eval()'d
>   code on line 46

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could highlight the lines the errors are talking about. A comment saying `// Line 29` or whatever would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call return, it quits the function at that point, and it doesn't return literally $info so you can keep using that name, but the data inside of that variable.

At the end of your library, change the three returns to something like:

```
return array('num_count' => $info, 'results' => $results, 'offset' => $offset);
```

This will return an associative array.

and in your controller:

```
  $data = $this->siran->show($where, $table, $url_pag);
```

Where $data will become that array returned by the library.

Comment: this: `return ["num_count" => $info, "results" => $results, "offset" => $offset];` have this error: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in D:\xampp\htdocs\Siran-mehdi\application\libraries\Siran.php on line 61** ???

Answer (score 0):

Return it as array

```
return array('num_count' => $info, 'results' => $results, 'offset' => $offset);
```

And actually, in MVC pattern, that much like Model job instead library, since it related with your database abstraction. You create a Library for other task, which ussually is a common task you need.

Comment: The use of Model is cause reduce the speed site. !? I am using this library in several other...